# Fluid arrangment of dynamic tables

Tags: html, css

I had a question with regards to fluid arrangement of tables. I have attached a screen-shot below to try and explain what I am trying to achieve.

Basically, I have a number of dynamically created tables. Their widths are fixed but their heights can vary. What I am trying to achieve is, the maximum utilization of space when the browser window is re-sized (in terms of organization of the tables).

I have tried the following:
1. Arrange the tables in descending order of the number of rows they have.
2. Using a style of 'float: left;' on the table (or a div surrounding the table).

However, as you can see below, there is a gap below on the first column that could have been utilized by table 4 (the last one below), but it hasn't because table 3 (column 2, row 2) is taking up some space which prevents table 4 from being placed above.

I hope I've described it in a manner that could be understood, if not please let me know how I could clarify any points so that you could help me out.

Basically trying to get a fluid design with the maximum space utilization. Any ideas on how I could achieve this?

Thanks in advance.
[Example http://img717.imageshack.us/img717/5492/exampleqm.jpg](http://img717.imageshack.us/img717/5492/exampleqm.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [jQuery Masonry](http://desandro.com/resources/jquery-masonry/) plug-in.

Answer (score 1):

Can't be done without javascript (or a whole lot of assumptions and restrictions).

Try the [Columnizer jQuery Plugin](http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/).